# why dblclick does not work in my Vue js app

Tags: vue.js, drag, movable, ondblclick

I have two movable elements in my page & I like to log something in the console when I double click on the first movable object.
I call the dblclick event but it's not triggered.I like to know how I can solve this problem. My code is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-frog-o99k6?file=/src/App.vue:242-251)

Comment: There's no `dblclick` anywhere in the code you linked. Please update the question to show what you tried in setting up this event handler.

Comment: @tony19 thanks for letting me know. I updated it

Comment: Since you only want to listen for event on first movable object, a simpler solution would be to wrap your first movable object in a div and add the dblclick event to the div.
[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-resonance-5gwve?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: @Raja I checked your solution but it does not work. I don't see anything in the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sandbox [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-resonance-5gwve?file=/src/App.vue) with a working example GIF.

[image: Working Example]